# Ruby on Rails - Trouble looping through partial using collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, partials

I am having issues using the :collection command for a partial within a form I am creating in rails. I would ideally like to use the :collection command, so I can easily manipulate this section in my .rjs templates (the form will submit and reload the form when the check box is changed, it's a to-do list).

This code works:

```
<% form_for "list[]", :url => {:action => "checkbox_update"} do |f| %>
      <ul id="lists_not_completed">
           <% for @list in @lists %>
               <%= render :partial => @list,  :locals => {:f =>f, :complete => FALSE } %>   
          <% end %>
      </ul>
<% end %>
```

with the partial:

```
<% if @list.completed == complete %>
        <li><%= f.check_box :completed %>
                <%=h @list.name %>

        <%= link_to 'Show', list %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_list_path(list) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', list, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></li>
<% end %>
```

This code does not work, but I would like it to use this form:

```
<% form_for "list[]", :url => {:action => "checkbox_update"} do |f| %>
  <ul id="lists_not_completed">
      <%= render :partial => 'list', :collection => @lists, :locals => {:f =>f, :complete => FALSE } %> 
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

with the non-working partial:

```
<% if list.completed == complete %>
        <li><%= f.check_box :completed %>
                <%=h list.name %>

        <%= link_to 'Show', list %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_list_path(list) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', list, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></li>
<% end %>
```

I get the error:

object[] naming but object param and @object var don't exist or don't respond to to_param: nil. It is referring to this line: `<li><%= f.check_box :completed %>`. I'm not sure if why this doesn't work and have tried many, many different variations, but I can't get it working. Is the form preventing me from doing this? The form_for code is straight from the Rails Way book for listing multiple objects from one model in a form.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is you've not got @list defined anywhere when you're using the render :partial with a :collection.

The system is looking for @list to match the list[] when you call f.check_box

you could set @list = list in your partial to get around that. I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer is correct, but I'd probably avoid extracting the partial within the form_for loop altogether.  I suppose it's a matter of style, but I think the confusion here isn't really worth the cleanup that the partial represents in this case.  I'd probably write a partial that included the whole form.